# Identify object calling draw() method with OpenGL

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Is there a way to identify which object is calling the draw method.

Creation:

```
joint.model = [[Box alloc] init];
```

The calling code:

```
    [joint.model draw];
```

The draw method (within Box class):

```
-(void)draw
{   
        glBindVertexArrayOES(_boxVAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 7055*3);
}
```

How can i receive the `joint` object in my draw method?

If more class info is necessary i can attach, but i did not assume since theres not much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `model` object needs to have a pointer back to `joint` in order to use it in the `-draw` method. So you need to either modify the `Box` class to have a pointer to whatever type `joint` is, or if `Box` is defined by a framework you're using, you need to subclass it. So you could do either:

```
@class Box {
   Model* model; // Or whatever type model is.
}
```

Or if that's not an option, you could do this:

```
@class BetterBox : Box {
    Model* model; // Or whatever type model is.
}
```

And make sure that `model.joint` is created like this:

```
model.joint = [[BetterBox alloc] init]; // or [[Box alloc] init] if you modified the Box class
[model.joint setModel:model];
```

Then in your draw method, you can simply access `model` like this:

```
- (void)draw
{
    [model someMethod];
    //... etc. ...
}
```

Comment: The reason why i need this functionality is in order to use a named constant. But how do i use the `self` in this situation? How can i access `joint.jointName` attribute which i can identify my object with?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you wrote above. I thought `-draw` was a method of `joint`, but it's a method of `model`. In that case, self is `model`, and `model` needs to have a pointer to `joint`. Then you can simply call `[self.model doWhatever];`.

Comment: Ofcourse i forgot a part to clarify this. Please wait for a update.

Comment: Please see my edit now. `joint.model` is an object of `Box class`, within this class the `draw` method is called. Does that make sense?

Comment: I already have `@property (nonatomic, retain) Box *model;` in my `Joint.h`. But as i can see it wont benefit much..

Comment: Is there not a sneaky way to cast this object without making so many changes?

Comment: Could you post the definitions of both `joint` and `model`s classes? If you already have a pointer to the `model`, then you can simply use it in `joint`'s `-draw` method. I don't understand where your confusion is. Could you also describe in more detail what you're trying to do?

Comment: To dig down to the bones. Its because im loading 6 different 3D objects (in OpenGL) and calling the rendering through a ViewController. The draw method do not know which object they its calling on, so i cannot change the static size (which you complained about). In the class where i have the draw method i have 6 different variables with the sizes, i need to identify which object it is in and change the size.

Comment: `model` is a attribute with OpenGL rendering content of the particular object.

Comment: If i could modify the draw method and pass on a string, even that would do the trick. But as far as i can see its not possible to modify the `draw` method? I do not need a golden solution right now, it has to be quick and extreme dirty.